# lowest available number in a number sequence

Tags: loops, batch-file, numbers, sequence

OK. This one should be easy... but it's got me stumped. Working in Batch with .ini files, using section headers as key fields. Problem being those keys unsorted and with missing numbers. Simplification of the problem. Lets say I have an array, like so, in this order:

1, 12, 6, 2, 0

Thus, I'd like to apply a function and return "3"

I guess same function should be able to accommodate if next 'available' number is actually higher. For e.g.:

3,1,0,2 Should return 4.

Not so bothered about the coding side - should be some combo of For and in increasing count or something. I just can't figure the formula!

Closest I got was (pseudo):

```
A[1]=1
A[2]=12
A[3]=6  
(etc etc etc) 

set min=0
For count = 1 to {number of array components} 
If A[count]<count then (min=min+1)
```

But that failed in a certain scenario. Any ideas, or am I just batch brain frazzled?

Comment: How do we know these values you expect to return? They seem random,  and neither of your examples are elements of the array. Then in your code you are using count as both an index and value, with min being thrown in. It's a but of a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "missing="
FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,99) DO IF NOT DEFINED missing (
 find "[%%a]" q26445657.txt>NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET /a "missing=%%a"
)
ECHO I'd choose %missing% if I were you...

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q26445657.txt` containing this data for my testing.

```
[3]
data
[4]
data
[1]
data
[12]
data
[0]
some data
```

Almost inevitably, your attempt at simplification led to a more difficult-to-solve problem. As you say, this is an `.ini` file, so I can only assume the standard format for such a file. A representative data sample would have been far more use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to sort them first (0 , 1 , 3 , 6 , 12 ) then do a for loop in which you subtract each element in the array with the previous one 
e.g

```
A[1]=1
A[2]=12
A[3]=6  
A[4]=2
A[5]=0
```

After sorting

```
A[1]=0
A[2]=1
A[3]=2  
A[4]=6
A[5]=12
```

subtract A[index]-A[index-1] with a condition ==1 (this mean both are consecutive) 
whenever this breaks you will get your returned value, this will break on 3rd iteration since 6-2 not equal to 1. Hope this what you want

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below solve your simplified problem, but it may be easily used to process an .ini file (I will modify the code if you post your .ini file). The complications in the code are needed because the variables are sorted in alphabetical order, so it is necessary to insert left zeros in the indices.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "sequence=1,12,6,2,0"

set min=0
rem Process each number in sequence
for %%i in (%sequence%) do (
   set /A i=1000+%%i
   rem Create new array elements in ascending order up to current number
   if not defined A[!i!] (
      for /L %%j in (!min!,1,%%i) do (
         set /A j=1000+%%j
         set A[!j!]=%%j
      )
      set /A min=%%i+1
   )
   rem Delete current element
   set "A[!i!]="
)
rem Get the first undefined element
set "result="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set A[ 2^>NUL') do set "result=%%i" & goto continue
:continue
if not defined result set "result=%min%"
echo Result: %result%
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks folks - all really helpful answers. Yes, I see now that if you try and simplify it only makes it more complicated!

Answer chosen because suited the specifics of my situation the most. Just to tie it all together, the specifics below:

I did have an ini file in the standard format, i.e.

[0]

Data

[3]

Data

[1]

Data etc...

The reason why I was referencing arrays was that I have a function that extracts all of the section names (those in "[]") and puts them into an array. I think this only served to complicate the issue and Magoo's answer cut to the chase! Thanks again, all.